# GridViewColumnHeader.Click, How to detect which column was clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

Been messing with this and can't seem to figure it out.  It seems that the object sender is actually the ListView.. so even though if I figure out how to get the GridViewColumn as a child... I don't know how to distinguish which column was actually clicked?

```
<ListView x:Name="SingleTweet_ListView" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          MouseLeftButtonUp="SingleTweet_ListView_MouseLeftButtonUp"
          Height="200" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="12" 
          GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Screen Name"
                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" Width="112"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Tweet"
                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" Width="623"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

```
void GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((GridViewColumn)sender).Header.ToString());
    //error cus the sender is actually the listview?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sender will be `ListView` but you can check for `OriginalSource` which will be `GridViewColumnHeader` and can get column from it:

```
MessageBox.Show(((GridViewColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource).Column
                 .Header.ToString());
```

Comment: thank you!  worked perfectly.  i have to wait 8 minutes to give you answer

Comment: ah thank you for the edit, having the explanation rather than just a code helps alot more as far as understanding, thanks!